# How to make a html element show a value after a grpc call(or other async method) with blazor?

Tags: grpc, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm testing with blazor and grpc, and I'm trying to follow this tutorial(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ynZlJ3pACpI) which seems to be outdated. Either way, with some adaptations it should work, even because there aren't out there many examples or tutorials.
The problem is that the value on the html element is not updated with the grpc response.

I'm supposed to have this:

```
@page "/greeter"
@inject GrpcService1.GreeterService GreeterService1

@using BlazorApp1.Data

<h1>Grpc Connection</h1>

<input type="text" @bind="@Name" />
<button onclick="@SayHello">Button</button>

<p>@Greetmsg</p>

@code {
    string Name;
    private string Greetmsg;

    async void SayHello()
    {
        this.Greetmsg = await this.GreeterService1.SayHello(this.Name);
    }

}
```

But something may had been updated because I cannot call the SayHello method that way. I must put the @ before the Onclick, otherwise I get the error "Cannot convert method group to no delegate type".
So I put it like this:

```
<button @onclick="SayHello">Button</button>
```

This way it works but the result I get from the grpc server only shows up when pressing the button for the next request. I followed the code execution and the request is made, the response comes, but the value on the page isn't updated. Then the code execution ends and still no update. When I press the button for a new request the value somehow is updated.

I also added another button

```
<button @onclick="SayHello">SayHello</button>
<button @onclick="updateGreetmsg">updateGreetmsg</button>
```

With an empty function below the other one

```
    public void updateGreetmsg()
    {

    }
```

And it is enough to call that function to the earlier received value get shown.
So the await thing is not working in the first function, where it is supposed to.

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `async Task SayHello()`
Don't use void... use Task instead.

[Avoid async void methods](https://haacked.com/archive/2014/11/11/async-void-methods/)

Your button element should be defined as follows:

```
<button @onclick="@SayHello">SayHello</button>
```

Note: the onclick attribute is not the normal Html element's onclick attribute. It should be preceded with the '@' sign, and it is called a compiler directive.

> Razor components also make extensive use of directive attributes  (@onclick, @bind, @ref, and so on) on elements to control various aspects of how components get compiled (event handling, data binding, component & element references, and so on).

[Read more...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/blazor-for-web-forms-developers/components)

Note also that after a UI event, such as the above, your component is automatically re-rendered. In the past, we had to call the StateHasChanged method to notify the component that its state has changed, and that it may render. Currently, if you wish to re-render your component due to an alteration of the component's state caused by non UI events, you should call the StateHasChanged method

Comment: Wonderful enet. Thank you so much!
I'm right now checking some paid courses to learn Blazor wich will avoid me to do these basic questions. Thank you

Comment: @Ricardo Araújo, would you mind marking it as the answer if it solved your problem, so others know it was useful.

Comment: Ok, it is done. I clicked the accepted check mark. I didn't knew i could, and should do that. you're welcome.